# rosoct/ corobot support

Tags: ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently working with a coroware bot with a fellow student intern. We are using a matlab interface in Windows, which is working alright for now. However, we foresee latency issues among other problems that may creep up in the future (since the program structure implements at least 3 different programming languages).

We would like to implement the bot using the ros software and using an octave interface. I am aware that rosoct has been retired and is no longer being distributed on this website. I am also aware that ros and coroware are currently working on drivers that support one another.

Is there any hope to have a future rosoct distribution in the works (possibly to interface with diamondback) and is there anyone that possibly has the libraries associated with rosoct still?
Also, when is the coroware/ros software expecting to be released?

Thanks ahead of time for your comments/replies

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10165/rosoct/-corobot-support/) by [Seanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/654/seanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosoct would need a new maintainer willing to migrate it.  An alternative is to use rospy with matplotlib.

The libraries associated with rosoct are still available here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_experimental/branches/cturtle/rosoct

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1